# Appium An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: ios, ruby, appium

i download the sample code on Appium website.

i have xcode 6.4 appium 1.4.13.

The i run the simple_test.rb, the code like this. iOS scimitar start ,and put values in textfields. but when click the first button.
error messages come out ,even if i sleep some time, the message is still.

> info: [debug] [INST] 2015-11-04 09:54:53 +0000 Debug: Got new command
>   7 from instruments: au.getElement('2').rect()
>
> info: [debug] Socket data received (83 bytes) info: [debug] Socket
>   data being routed. info: [debug] Got result from instruments:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"origin":{"x":94,"y":122},"size":{"width":113,"height":37}}}
>
> info: [debug] [INST] 2015-11-04 09:54:53 +0000 Debug: evaluating
>   au.getElement('2').rect()
>          2015-11-04 09:54:53 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished 2015-11-04 09:54:53 +0000 Debug: responding with: 2015-11-04 09:54:53 +0000
>   Debug: Running system command #8:
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js
>   /tmp/instruments_sock
>   2,{"status":0,"value":{"origin":{"x":94,"y":122},"size":{"width":113,"height":37}}}...
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error:
>   {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command. (Original error: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED)","code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","origValue":"connect
>   ECONNREFUSED"},"sessionId":"e7e398a0-e68d-4b71-8a74-1eef7fd6e948"}
>   info: <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/e7e398a0-e68d-4b71-8a74-1eef7fd6e948/element/2/click
>   500 138.558 ms - 293

......

## Start the driver

Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps).start_driver

module Calculator
  module IOS
    # Add all the Appium library methods to Test to make
    # calling them look nicer.
    Appium.promote_singleton_appium_methods Calculator

```
# Add two numbers
values       = [rand(10), rand(10)]
expected_sum = values.reduce(&:+)

# Find every textfield.
elements     = textfields

elements.each_with_index do |element, index|
  element.type values[index]
end

# wait { text 'Computer Sum' }
sleep(30)
button(1).click
```

Comment: Did you check if appium server was running ?

Answer (score 0):

1. install ios-webkit-debug-proxy by command:
   brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy
2. Run ios-webkit-debug-proxy on terminal.
3. ios-webkit-debug-proxy requires the "web inspector" to be turned on to allow a connection to be established with iOS Device. To Turn it on Go to settings > safari > advanced > web inspector - On. Try now.